# Assembler x86 without stdlib

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, 32-bit

I want to read command line arguments when an assembly program is run. Do I have to use `sys_read` or something else?

I know how to access data using things like scanf.  For instance:

```
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, msg
mov edx len
int 0x80
```

What I'm looking for, though, are the command line arguments.  When I execute `./a.out 45 23` I want to get access to the '45' for example.

And so, if anybody have a page where the unixstd.h defined... I would be grateful.

Comment: The command line arguments are passed to you using an OS-specific way. For ELF32 linux, you get them on the stack. See [Startup state of a Linux/i386 ELF binary](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/startup.html#st).

Comment: So, i tried it and it looks like this : 
**pop eax ;
pop ebx ;
mov ecx, offset msg;
mov [ecx], eax**;

But when i want to write it on screen... Then it's just random characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing command line arguments under ELF32 Linux is available through the stack:

```
mov eax, [esp+8]
mov ebx, [eax]
mov ecx, offset msg
mov [ecx], ebx
```

Credit to @Jester for his answer in the comments!